# How to add stringified object to end of url

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6, uri

I am trying to take a json object such as this one:

```
filters = {"filters": myArray};
```

and append it to the end of a url using:

```
this.router.navigate([`/devices/${productType}/${deviceCategory}/${JSON.stringify(filters)}`]);
```

Anyway, so I read on other forums that using encodeURIComponent should be used so then I tried the following:

```
this.router.navigate([`/devices/${productType}/${deviceCategory}/${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filters))}`]);
```

At this point I dont get errors but, when I try to get the data from `params.paramId.filters` I get undefined, even if I decode or parse it with `JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(params.paramId.filters));`

How can I add a stringified object to a url and then retrieve it from the params to continue using it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to consider encoding that as a query string instead of sticking JSON in path segments.

Answer (score 1):

### Encoding

First do this:

```
const source = new URLSearchParams(filters).toString();
```

and append this to your url:

```
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(source));
```

---

### Decoding

Do this:

```
var search = location.search.substring(1);
var filters = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURIComponent(search).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g,'","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}');
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was, I imported `NavigationExtras`, then:

`let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {queryParams: {"filters": JSON.stringify(this.searchValues)}};`

in my function where I was trying to append the parameter to the link, and added it like this:

`this.router.navigate(['/devices/${this.config.productType.toLowerCase()}/${this.deviceCategory}/${this.displayMode}'], navigationExtras);`

I retrieved it like this:

`this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(param => { this.finalSearchValues = param["filters"] ? {"Filters": JSON.parse(param["filters"])} : {"filters":[]}; console.log(this.finalSearchValues);});`

And it seems to be working for me at the moment. Thank you for your answers guys.